# Variables in NumPy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

In NumPy, I'm trying to represent differential equations of the form: `y' = p(t)y + g(t)`, where `p(t)` is an nxn matrix and and `g(t)` is an nx1 matrix. Something like:

```
y' = [[1,5], [2,1]] + [[e^t], [1]]
```

I know how to represent matrices in NumPy, but how would I represent matrices that contain variables (for example, `2t` or `e^t`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'variable' in this sense (as in, `y` is a function of `t`) should probably be represented by a 1d array of that variable's domain.  This would increase the dimension of your array (making it `(n, n, m)` where `m` is the size of your domain (length of `t`).

If you plan on using a scipy ode solver, then you write it as a function, so instead of

```
t = np.arange(0, 10, .1)
y' = [[1,5]*len(t), [2,1]*len(t)] + [[np.exp(t)], [1]*len(t)]
```

you need to do something like:

```
def yderiv(t):
    return [[1,5], [2,1]] + [[np.exp(t)], [1]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `e^t` does what you expect it to. Did you mean something like `np.exp(t)`?

Comment: @Hooked yeah. The matrix can contain variables.

Comment: Thanks @Hooked, you're probably right.  I just copied from above.

Comment: @askewchan yes I do mean that. I'm trying to solve ODEs on my own without SciPy using NumPy. Maybe use SciPy integration but I need solve the actual ODE alone and not using a library. To use a 1d array of that variable's domain, would it be like: `g = [2t, 1, 2], where the last element 2 is the size? I'm afraid I don't get it.

Comment: numpy.poly1d represents a polynomial. A matrix [[np.exp(t)], [1]] is not a polynomial, however.

np.exp(t) throws an error when used alone since t is not defined.

Comment: @Darksky sorry, I should make my answer more clear, `t` is supposed to be a 1d array of the domain of _t_ that you wish to study.

Comment: @askewchan So how would I allow a user to input an ODE in terms of `t`? Right now, I use: `raw_input` and ask for stdin in the form of: `1 2 3; 4 5 6` and use `numpy.mat(the_input)` but if a user enters `t`, an error is thrown.

Comment: @Darksky I'm not sure I entirely understand your goals.  The matrix must be defined as a function of any variables, and those variables must be given as parameters.  You cannot simply use `t` or `x` in place of a number, because numpy (python, really) deals with numerical values, not symbols.

Comment: I think I understand. Perhaps have the user input the exact matrices, and not the matrix in terms of variables.

Comment: @Darksky Yes or perhaps allow the user to input `-1` or `np.nan` or `None` instead of an integer, and then change the matrix later to replace those values with the variable in a function.